# Handling spring reactor exceptions in imperative spring application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-reactor

I'm using the webflux in an imperative spring boot application. In this app I need to make rest calls to various backends using webclient and wait on all the responses before proceeding to the next step.

ClassA

```
public ClassA
{
     public Mono<String> restCall1()
     {
          return webclient....exchange()...
                 .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(maxAttempts, Duration.ofSeconds(minBackOff))
                 .filter(this::isTransient)
                 .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> {
                     return new MyCustomException();
        });
     }
}
```

ClassB

```
public ClassB
{
     public Mono<String> restCall2()
     {
          return webclient....exchange()...
                 .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(maxAttempts, Duration.ofSeconds(minBackOff))
                 .filter(this::isTransient)
                 .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> {
                     return new MyCustomException();
        });
     }
}
```

```
Mono<String> a = classAObj.restCall1();
Mono<String> b = classBObj.restCall2();

ArrayList<Mono<String>> myMonos = new ArrayList<>;

myMonos.add(a);
myMonos.add(b);

try {
List<String> results = Flux.mergeSequential(myMonos).collectList().block();} 
catch(WebclientResponseException e) {
.... 
}
```

The above code is working as expected. The Webclient is configured to throw error on 5xx and 4xx which I'm able to catch using WebclientResponseException.

The problem is I'm unable to catch any exceptions from the react framework. For example my web clients are configured to retry with exponential backoff and throw exception on exhaustion and I have no way to catch it in my try catch block above. I explored the option to handle that exceptiom in the webclient stream using onErrorReturn but it does not propagate the error back to my subscriber.

I also cannot add the exception to the catch block as it's never being thrown by any part of the code.

Can anyone advice what is the best way to handle these type of error. scenarios. I'm new to webflux and reactive programming.

Comment: is there a base exception in react that can be added to my catch block?

Comment: Instead of posting code that does work, could you please instead post code that doesn’t work. Chances will be higher of help then.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf This is the code that is having the issue. I'm able to make concurrent rest api calls. The problem is I'm not able to catch any errors throws by the reactor framework.

Comment: is this a webflux application, or is this a springMVC application using the webclient?

Comment: Its is a webflux app but not an reactive application. We are using webflux to achieve concurrency.